# Material-ui: outline version of icon

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material-ui in my react web application. I need the icon 'action/description' in a component but in the *outline* version.

According to the docs:

> For convenience, the full set of google Material icons are available
>   in Material-UI as pre-built SVG Icon components.

So I can do this to get the "filled" version:

```
import ActionDescription from 'material-ui/svg-icons/action/description'

<div className="number">
  <ActionDescription />
</div>
```

But how do I get the "outline" version? I tried playing with css but didn't succeed:

```
<div>
  <ActionDescription style={{black: "black"}} color="transparent" />
</div>
```

Comment: You can find a list of all the icons available here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/packages/material-ui-icons/src It seems like the one you want is not there yet. But you can suggest someone add it. I noticed some icons have the ~Outline suffix.

Answer (score 10):

Not sure if this was available when you posed the original question, but from the official v1.3.1 documentation:

> For "themed" icons, append the theme name to the icon name. For instance with the
>
> - The Outlined delete icon is exposed as @material-ui/icons/BuildOutlined
> - The Rounded delete icon is exposed as @material-ui/icons/BuildRounded
> - The Two Tone delete icon is exposed as @material-ui/icons/BuildTwoTone
> - The Sharp delete icon is exposed as @material-ui/icons/BuildSharp

See https://material-ui.com/style/icons/

edit: confirmed that this requires the latest beta package of `@material/icons` which may not have been available a few months ago.  Install with:

```
npm install @material-ui/icons@2.0.0-beta.1
```

and you should be able to access the themed icon sets mentioned in the recent docs.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in icons are in filled style, so I think you have to manually make the outlined one.

I downloaded the svg file here: [material icons official site](https://material.io/tools/icons/?search=descrip&icon=description&style=outline).

Then you can add custom svg icon like this: (this is the outlined description icon)

```
import SvgIcon from 'material-ui/SvgIcon';

    <SvgIcon>
      <g>
        <rect x="8" y="16" width="8" height="2"/>
        <rect x="8" y="12" width="8" height="2"/>
        <path d="M14,2H6C4.9,2,4,2.9,4,4v16c0,1.1,0.89,2,1.99,2H18c1.1,0,2-0.9,2-2V8L14,2z M18,20L6,20V4h7v5h5V20z"/>
      </g>
    </SvgIcon>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to Marson Mao: Here is the guide for [custom SVG Icons](https://v0.material-ui.com/#/components/svg-icon).
Further, SvgIcon only needs the **path**.
Working example:

```
const ActionDescriptionOutline = (props) => (
  <SvgIcon {...props}>
    <path d="M14,2H6C4.9,2,4,2.9,4,4v16c0,1.1,0.89,2,1.99,2H18c1.1,0,2-0.9,2-2V8L14,2z M18,20L6,20V4h7v5h5V20z"/>
  </SvgIcon>
);

<RaisedButton
  icon={<ActionDescriptionOutline />}
  onClick={this.handleToggle}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional information! I use the `<g>` here because that icon asked by OP is using some `<rect>` along with `<path>`, so the `<g>` is needed. It's just that you could put any valid structure inside `<SvgIcon>`.