# Unable to import outlined svg icon component material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, google-material-icons

I am using material icons in by react application.
I wanted to use circular check.

I could import and use the [check_circle](https://material.io/tools/icons/?icon=check_circle&style=round) icon as follows

```
import CheckCircle from 'material-ui/svg-icons/action/check-circle';
```

There is another icon called  [circle_check_outline](https://material.io/tools/icons/?icon=check_circle_outline&style=round) which I am unable to import by the normal import line

```
import CheckCircleOutline from 'material-ui/svg-icons/action/check-circle-outline';
```

It gives `Can't resolve 'material-ui/svg-icons/action/check-circle-outline'` error

I tried downloading the icon and render it as suggested in [Marson Mao's answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50327142/material-ui-outline-version-of-icon) in stackoverflow

```
import SvgIcon from 'material-ui/SvgIcon';
import CheckCircleOutline from '../../assets/check-circle-outline.svg';

  <SvgIcon>
    {CheckCircleOutline}
  </SvgIcon>
```

Then I got the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'svgIcon' of undefined
    at SvgIcon.render
```

I also tried Joey T 's answer in the same question. Installed @material/icons package using `npm install @material-ui/icons@2.0.0-beta.1`

and imported the icon as follows

```
import CheckCircleOutline from '@material/icons/CheckCircleOutline';
```

Still getting the error

```
Can't resolve '@material/icons/CheckCircleOutline'
```

I am using material-ui v0

Comment: 'material-ui/svg-icons/action/check_circle-outline' Is that an underscore, when you are importing? If so, replace with hyphen

Comment: @cdoshi No it is a hyphen.. I changed it in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The material-ui does not have check-circle-outline icon, hence it gives an error when importing. What you can do is get the latest icons from @material-ui/icons and then import them

Install the package by using the following command

```
npm install @material-ui/icons
```

Then import it,

```
import CheckCircleOutline from '@material-ui/icons/CheckCircleOutline';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
import CheckCircleoutline from '@material-ui/icons/CheckCircleOutline';
```

Use `<CheckCircleoutline />`